# How can I access VPN through Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm developing a project and I need the Android Studio emulator to access the database through a VPN. This is the step by step of what the emulator needs to do: Emulator needs to access the VPN to have access to a website where I will login and password. (I'm not using a macbook).
Dart, Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to connect the VPN:

1- you can install "open vpn" directly on the emulator (remembering that the emulator has to be enabled for internet and google play).

2- you can install "open vpn" on a physical device to use.

Comment: I put the "open vpn" as an example, but feel free to use any vpn.